# Set default values for inherited IB-properties

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch

I wrote a UILabel-subclass called *Badge* that is supposed to display notifications similar to Apple's icon-badges. I made *Badge* customizable in Interface Builder by prefixing it with `@IBDesignable` and its properties with `@IBInspectable`. The setup works both from code and IB, where it is rendering properly. The only thing I'm struggling with is setting up new default-values for the inherited `@IBDesignable`-properties such as `text` and `backgroundColor`. I have tried to set these values in the `init`-methods and also `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()`, but the values in the Attributes Inspector in the `UILabel` and `UIView`-section remain unchanged.

**Here my question:**
Is it possible to change/override the `UILabel`'s default text found in the Attributes Inspector so that a custom text instead of "Label" is rendered in IB for my subclass by default?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?